# postback for reast ai sap conversation

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, artificial-intelligence, sap-conversational-ai

Recast ai Or Sap Conversational Bot

**I want to know the postback for recast ai means when someone click on quick replies it can answer from webhook**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express() 
const port = 5000 
app.use(bodyParser.json()) 
// response
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)

  res.send({
    replies: [{
        type: 'quickReplies',
        content: {
          title: 'Sorry, but I could not find any results for your request :(',
          buttons: [{ title: 'get quiz', value: 'quiz' }],
        },
      },)
})

app.post('/errors', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body) 
  res.send() 
}) 

app.listen(port, () => { 
  console.log('Server is running on port 5000') 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The postback would be the value of the quick reply. Meaning: when a user is going to click on the button the value is going to be sent to the builder. If you want to trigger a webhook from the postback the trick consists of having a unique value such as **POSTBACK** and then you can set this as a trigger from another skill doing if _source is **POSTBACK** then do a webhook call.

Hope that answers the question :)